# Firewall Security

Tags: security, firewall

My company just moved office to a new building and the Internet company came to install the internet (fiber). The problem is that the telco company installed the router in the basement of the building (which it happens to be the parking of the building also). That means that the internet router for my company is at the basement, wide in the open. The router has 3 free ports, that means that potentially anyone that walks-by at the parking can plug-in a laptop and get into our network (not only use the internet but try to hack into our file servers, etc...). We are a software company.

Did we try to get router upstairs? Yes but after several discussions with the telco company, it seems we have no choice with this setup. Therefore, does anyone recommend a good solution to protect our network? First thing comes to mind is to purchase a Firewall Hardware box and plug that inside our office from the internet cable that comes from the wall. Would that be the best solution? And if yes, any recommendations for a not too expensive firewall hardware? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This site is for programming questions **only**. This question is off topic and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, modern routers nowadays should already have port security features built-in. So, optimistically, you may not need to purchase a hardware firewall.
On the other hand, if you can afford to lock the router into a frame/cage, that's also a mean of physical access control. Installing a security camera near the router is another option.

Comment: Do not answer off-topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for your case is using [packet filtering](https://www.ixiacom.com/products/packetstack).
It is a firewall technique used to control network access by monitoring outgoing and incoming packets and allowing them to pass or halt based on the source and destination IP addresses, protocols and ports.

A product that can suit your needs is Ixia's PacketStack. Its packet filtering capabilities can be used without any packet loss, you can anipulate traffic anyway you want - deduplicate, stamp and trim. You can hide or overwrite sensitive or personally identifiable information before providing the data to analysis tools.